# How to return response from Worker in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have created a worker in .net core which calculates fibonacci series. But I need to be able to read this series as a response from this worker. And I am very new to this so after several hours of research I could not find the solution.

Here is my code:

```
 public class FibonacciCalculateWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<FibonacciCalculateWorker> _logger;

    public FibonacciCalculateWorker(ILogger<FibonacciCalculateWorker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await CreateFibonacciSeries();

    }
    public Task<string> CreateFibonacciSeries()
    {
        int a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;
        StringBuilder fiboSeries = new StringBuilder();
        fiboSeries.Append(a + "," + b);

        for (int i = 2; i < 50; i++)
        {
            c = a + b;

            fiboSeries.Append("," + c);
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
        _logger.LogInformation(fiboSeries.ToString());
        return Task.FromResult(fiboSeries.ToString());
    }
}
```

And program.cs:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<FibonacciCalculateWorker>();
            });
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Read it how, from where? A standalone process has nothing to write *to* except standard output, and you can't read the output of a Windows service. You'll need some form of inter-process communication (IPC) like setting up a web endpoint or (the very poor man's IPC) write things to a file.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for the suggestion. Could you please suggest how to set up the web endpoint from worker?

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service) for generic information on how to host ASP.NET as a Windows service. The code for your worker service may need some changes to respond to requests rather than go off calculating on its own.

Comment: That's not how `BackgroundService`s are supposed to be used. They cannot return data to the caller and it wouldn't make sense if they did. Why would the caller off-load work into a `BackgroundService` if it still depended on the result of the calculation? In that scenario the caller should do the work itself. Use `BackgroundService`s when you have jobs whose lifetime is similar to the hosting app or that run in scheduled intervals.